# i wanted to switch tabs by one button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

my problem is that when you press the TAB button it shows the word profile, and if you press it again it should show the word home

currently, when I click on Tab, it switches to profile, but again when I click on Tab, it should switch to home, but it doesn't switch.

```js
const tab1 = document.querySelector('#tab11')
const tab2 = document.querySelector('#tab12')

const allTabPane = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane')

tab1.addEventListener('click', toggleTabs);
tab2.addEventListener('click', toggleTabs);

function clickTab(tab) {
  if (tab.parentNode.classList.contains('active') === false) tab.click();
}

function toggleTabs(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
    let toClick = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('li:not(.active) > a');
    setTimeout(function() {
      toClick.click();
    }, 10);
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid #000 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-bg {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding: 50px;
  color: blueviolet;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel-heading">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a class="tab-bg" href="#" id="tab11" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">TAB</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="tab12" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false"></a>
      </li>

  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-tab-pane">Home</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane">Profile</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/ayana07/pen/oNdMBmj).

Comment: Hi, it is because in the function where you are selecting toClick element, the element you are checking is the element with id=tab12, and this element will never have the active class because you are not adding it to it

Answer (score 0):

**Working code**

```js
$('.tab-bg').on('click', function () {
   $('.tab-bg').closest("li").toggleClass("active");
  $(".tab-pane").toggleClass("active fade show");
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 50%;
    border: solid #000 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}

.tab-bg{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.tab-pane{
    padding: 50px;
    color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel-heading">
                
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a class="tab-bg" href="#" id="tab11" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">TAB</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="tab12" data-bs-toggle="tab" class="tab-bg"  data-bs-target="#profile-tab-pane" role="tab" aria-controls="profile-tab-pane" aria-selected="false"></a>
        </li>
        
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane  show active" id="home-tab-pane">Home</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-tab-pane">Profile</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```